# AVX2 1x mm256i 32bit to 2x mm256i 64bit

Tags: c, simd, avx2

Is there a normal way to converted from 1x __m256i with 32bit ints into 2x __m256i's filled with 64bit ints. I'm averaging data and my 32bit ints are overflowing. So i'd like to split the accumulator register into two 64 bit registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using _mm256_unpackhi_epi32 and _mm256_unpacklo_epi32 with 0 value for parameter b. Here is a example just preforming a average.

```c
#define DATA_SIZE 16

__declspec(align(16)) static int buf[] = {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
};


__m256i zero = { 0 }; 
__m256i accumulated = { 0 };

for (int idx = 0; idx < DATA_SIZE; idx = idx + 8)
{
    //load data from buf
    __m256i int32data = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(buf + idx)); 

    __m256i data2 = _mm256_unpackhi_epi32(int32data, zero); //extract 4 ints
    __m256i data3 = _mm256_unpacklo_epi32(int32data, zero); //extract 4 more

    accumulated = _mm256_add_epi64(accumulated, data2); //accumulate first 4
    accumulated = _mm256_add_epi64(accumulated, data3); //accumulate 2nd 4
}

__m256i averageVec;
_mm256_store_si256(&averageVec, accumulated); //unload accumulated vector

//calculate the average
long long average = (averageVec.m256i_i64[0] + averageVec.m256i_i64[1]
    + averageVec.m256i_i64[2] + averageVec.m256i_i64[3])
    / DATA_SIZE;

printf("Average is: %d\n", average);
```

Comment: Note that your average calculation is non-portable - it only works with Visual C (and therefore only on Windows), which may be fine for your application, but you should be aware of this if you're interested in writing cross-platform code.

Comment: you mean i'm using long long instead of __int64?

Comment: Well for portability that should indeed be a standard type (`int64_t` - neither `long long` nor `__int64` are portable), but what I was referring to was the use of `.m256i_i64[n]`, which is a Microsoft-ism.

Answer (score 2):

As a building block, you're looking for the `VPMULDQ` instruction, or [_mm256_mul_epi32](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_avx2_mul_epi.htm) intrinsic.

This does 32x32 -> 64 multiplication, but is slightly different from what you want. In this case, the source `ymm` registers contain four 32-bit values each, and outputs to a single register of four 64-bit values.

Per Intel's documentation:

```
DEST[63:0] ← SRC1[31:0] * SRC2[31:0]
DEST[127:64] ← SRC1[95:64] * SRC2[95:64]
DEST[191:128] ← SRC1[159:128] * SRC2[159:128]
DEST[255:192] ← SRC1[223:192] * SRC2[223:192]
```

So to get 8x32 * 8x32 -> two 4x64 registers, you need to split the work up:

```
void mul32to64(__m256i a, __m256i b, __m256i *reshi, __m256i *reslo)
{
    *reshi = _mm256_mul_epi32(
        _mm256_cvtepi32_epi64(_mm256_extracti128_si256(a, 1)),
        _mm256_cvtepi32_epi64(_mm256_extracti128_si256(b, 1)));

    *reslo = _mm256_mul_epi32(
        _mm256_cvtepi32_epi64(_mm256_castsi256_si128(a)),
        _mm256_cvtepi32_epi64(_mm256_castsi256_si128(b)));
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit overkill? There's an instruction that extends integers. Unless I overlooked something, `_mm256_cvtepu32_epi64` for unsigned and `_mm256_cvtepi32_epi64` for signed?

Comment: Thanks, too tired to SSE apparently.